# SQL Table Schema for IdentityServer4 PersistedGrantStore

Tags: identityserver4

I'm writing a PersistedGrantStore for IdentityServer 4 and want to persist to a Table in SQL server.

PersistedGrant has a key of type `string`, not a great choice but I'll use binary collation to compensate. `nvarchar(max)` for a primary key is a no-go as long as I get to play the DBA role.

Could anyone give us an indication on how long this field and all other string fields should be?

- Key
- Type
- SubjectId
- SessionId
- ClientId
- Description
- Data

It would also be great to know beforehand if we should add indexes for any of the fields ending with Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table create SQL statement is:

```
USE [IdentityServer]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PersistedGrants]    Script Date: 2021-12-21 21:17:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersistedGrants](
    [Key] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SubjectId] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [SessionId] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ClientId] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [CreationTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Expiration] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ConsumedTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Data] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PersistedGrants] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

You can find the SQL code for all the tables [here](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/tree/main/migrations/IdentityServerDb/Migrations)